# Plotting Integral of Exponential functions

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am trying to Plot an integral equation that involves exponential function.
My code is as follow,

```
w=1;
L[α_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   1/(k + I*0.1) (
    Exp[I*k*x] (Exp[Sqrt[k^2 + α/w^2]*w] - 1) (Exp[k*w] - 1 + 
       I*0.1) Sqrt[
     k^2 + α/
      w^2])/((Sqrt[k^2 + α/w^2] + k) (Exp[
        Sqrt[k^2 + α/w^2]*w - Exp[k*w]]) + (Sqrt[
        k^2 + α/w^2] - 
        k) (Exp[(k + Sqrt[k^2 + α/w^2]) w] - 
        1)), {k, -100, 100}];
Plot[{Re[L[10]], Re[L[100]], Re[L[500]]}, {x, -0.45, 0.45}, 
 PlotRange -> Full].
```

But this integral gives a lot of oscillations which it should not. This is fig 2 in this article "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.00836.pdf" and Eq: 38 that I am trying to plot.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I included `w=1;`, what are you using?  I changed `L[alpha_]` to `L[alpha_,x_]` I changed your `I*0.1` to `I/10`and added `WorkingPrecision->32` to `NIntegrate` and changed `Plot` to `ListPlot[Table` with exact rational steps, all to see if this is a precision problem. I get errors about `NIntegrate` not being able to get 32 bits of precision and I still see the oscillations you see. Plotting your integrand shows it doesn't blow up but oscillates wildly so I am guessing that you need to find a way to tell `NIntegrate` that it has to work much harder to get accurate results from your integrand.

Comment: @Nasser, Thanks for pointing this out. w=1.

Comment: Consider the magnitude of the integrand around `k == 100`: `Block[{w = 1, \[Alpha] = 10, x = 0.10},
 Plot[
  Abs[
   1/(k + 
       I*0.) (Exp[
        I*k*x] (Exp[Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2]*w] - 1) (Exp[k*w] - 1 + 
         I*0.) Sqrt[
        k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2])/((Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2] + k) (Exp[
          Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2]*w - Exp[k*w]]) + (Sqrt[
           k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2] - 
          k) (Exp[(k + Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2]) w] - 1))
   ],
  {k, -200, 200}]
 ]`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the suggestions (thanks @Bill) and using `Method -> "LevinRule"`

```
L[\[Alpha]_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[1/(k + I/10) (Exp[I*k*x] (Exp[Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2]*w] - 1) (Exp[k*w] -1 + I/10) Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2])/((Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2] + k) (Exp[Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2]*w - Exp[k*w]]) + (Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2] - k) (Exp[(k + Sqrt[k^2 + \[Alpha]/w^2]) w] - 1)), {k, -100,100}
, Method -> "LevinRule"];
```

the integral can be evaluated and plotted without error message!

```
L[10, 0.4]
(*68.3565 - 3.11055 I*)

Plot[{Re[L[10, x]] }, {x, -0.45, 0.45}, PlotRange -> Full,Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: You should check your function !

Comment: Thanks, I am still working on it.